# "Class 'date' not found". Working with dates, getDate(), setDate() on php and js

Tags: javascript, php, date

I'm trying to implement some validations regarding the date of some db elements but the function date() doesn't seem to work at all.

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Class 'date' not found

Filename: BlaBlaBla

```js
$today = new date();
 $today.setDate($today.getDate()-5);
 foreach ($query as $item)
 {
  if ($item->startDateSP.getDate()>=$today.getDate())
   {
    $final.push($key);
   }
 }
```

The order or logic of that code is not important. The thing is that none of the date-related functions are recognized and an error shows up. I just want to know if there's a way to make those dates work

Comment: It's `Date`, identifiers are case-sensitive in JS. PS: php and js are 2 different independent languages, their standard libraries share nothing in common.

Comment: And to extend what zerkms is saying....they run in completely different environments at different times

Comment: If this is JS I would avoid using the `$` as a prefix on variables, as it is I can't tell if this is supposed to be PHP or JS.  For example this is JS `$final.push($key);`  But this is PHP `$item->startDateSP` or is it JS `$item->startDateSP.getDate()`.  To me it seems to be a weird mix of the two... lol

Comment: It's difficult because in JS the `.` is `->` in PHP and the `.` in PHP is concatenation or `+` in JS.  So it's easy to see a `.` and wonder if it's a function call (Js) or concatenation of a function call (PHP).   The `$` only add to that confusion if this is JS.  Right so this could be `$final.push($key)` calling push on something in JS,  or it could be concatenation in PHP of `$final` and some weird `push` function (which doesn't really make  sense) so you think this is JS, then you see this `$item->` and go oh its PHP..... maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to capitalize `Date()`, that's all:

```js
let today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() - 5);
console.log(today);
```

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina what I mean is it is all mixed with php code in question and needs to be isolated. Without that explanation OP is going down the wrong path

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina the problem is that you provided JS code while OP runs it on server with php interpreter.

Comment: Well yeah, that would be a problem. @Cead135, are you attempting to do this with PHP or Javascript?

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina the error message....and `foreach` ...and `$item->startDateSP` syntax is php

Comment: @charlietfl, yes I see that as well. The PHP and JS code are mixed together. Waiting on response from OP to post an update for either type

Comment: Unraveling this is a complete mess. Appears OP wants php code to validate db stuff

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to validate the dates resulting from the query, but it turns out to be better to do right from the consult itself. It's funny because everyone was just talking about what the heck was that code and I gont nothing on the actual problem. Edit: I get it is important to know what kind of code is there, is just something I did find funny.